# Why i get instant answer after press button in python telegram bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I got this code using PyTelegramBotAPI:

```
    elif call.data == 'search_chapter':
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, "Введите номер главы манги, которую вы ищете:")
        handle_search_chapter_input(chat_id,msg);


def handle_search_chapter_input(chat_id,msg):
    try:
        manga_name = chapter_selection[chat_id]['manga_name']  # Получаем значение manga_name из словаря
        chapter_number = msg.text
        conn = sqlite3.connect('manga_bot.db')
        cursor = conn.cursor()
        cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM chapters WHERE manga_name=? AND chapter_number=?",
                       (manga_name, chapter_number))
        chapter_data = cursor.fetchone()
        conn.close()
        if chapter_data is not None:
            chapter_title = chapter_data[3]
            chapter_url = chapter_data[4]
            chapter_number = chapter_data[2]
            result_message = f"Глава {chapter_number}: {chapter_title}\n\nСсылка на главу: {chapter_url}"
            bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=result_message)
        else:
            bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Некорректный номер главы. Пожалуйста, введите число.")
    except ValueError:
        bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text=".")
```

When i press "Search" button (call.data == 'search_chapter') bot sends me message from msg (bot.send_message(chat_id, "Введите номер главы манги, которую вы ищете:") and instant send message from handle_search_chapter_input function from Else (bot.send_message(chat_id=chat_id, text="Некорректный номер главы. Пожалуйста, введите число."). I dont get window to write message with number, i guess he just got empty message and try to find it end return with this message.

I add image so you can see how it looks like in telegram

I tried to change code a little, but its only getting worse.
I expect him to let me write chapter number after fisrt message and return correct data in result_message

Answer (score 0):

```
msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, "Введите номер главы манги, которую вы ищете:")
```

In this line `msg` stores a message, that was just sent by the bot, it doesn't wait for any actions by the user.
So then `handle_search_chapter_input(chat_id,msg)` runs instantly, and `msg.text` actually contains value `Введите номер главы манги, которую вы ищете:`.
Therefore, `chapter_data` is None and `else` statement is executed.

The way to wait for the user's input - is to use `bot.register_next_step_handler`. See the doc:
https://pytba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/sync_version/index.html#telebot.TeleBot.register_next_step_handler

First argument is the message after which you expect a reaction, and
second arument is a function that will be executed after that reaction.
The function should have `message` as an argument and in this case it will be the user's message, not the bot's.

You just need to fix the first part of your code a bit:

```
    elif call.data == 'search_chapter':
        chat_id = call.message.chat.id
        msg = bot.send_message(chat_id, "Введите номер главы манги, которую вы ищете:")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, handle_search_chapter_input)

def handle_search_chapter_input(msg):
    ...
```

That way when `handle_search_chapter_input` is called, it gets the user's message as an argument.
You can also add *args and **kwargs to `bot.register_next_step_handler` - they will be passed to the callback function (handle_search_chapter_input in this case).
But you don't actually need to pass `chat_id`, because `chat_id` equals to `message.chat.id`.

Hope that helps!